# How to make UISearchbar custom in iOS?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I want my UISearchbar should look like this.

[image: SEARCH BAR]

Is there any property to set or should I inherit it.

Please guide or any tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loupe"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image"]];

[self.searchBar setText:@"Search by keyword"];
```

Comment: which type of image is this, loupe
I will ask that from my designer, can you guide it.

Comment: also bg_image.png is which image in this desing?

Comment: @Duaan bg_image.png is the black image under your search field, loupe is a png image with alpha, in my case it was 20x19 pixels

Comment: I did background color, its woking fine, but LOUPE is not clear to me, can you give me your LOUPE.PNG to me, for just testing dear?

Comment: It should be `[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search by keyword"]` instead of `setText`.